# Running PHP project not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I am new to PHP.I have MySql,PHP and Apache2 installed in my ubuntu.and i have one webservice php file which i kept inside var/www.I have one html file inside var/www named hello.html.Apache2 is running properly i checked using localhost and also hello.html working fine.But while running php file, it's not working and all the contents of php file is getting displayed in my browser.Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if php is not installed run this codes

```
sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and try

Comment: as i told PHP5 is installed in my ubuntu.

Comment: if php is installed , php file will work. can you post contents of your php file?

Answer (score 0):

It means PHP is not installed or configured. Or you have to change the file permissions to read only. To reinstall it use

```
sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: i will try that but how html file is working ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller HTML doesn't need php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` (ubication may vary depending on distribution)

Be sure to have this line on your file in order to properly handle the php scripts:

> AddHandler php5-script .php

Comment: Hi I opened the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf using sudo gedit, but nothing is there written.what is wrong ?

Comment: This is the file location for RHEL / CentOS / SL, I do not know whether in Ubuntu based systems is in the same location. Anyway, try to grep files looking for that (AddHandler) in all your Apache configuration files.